# Solve the serie: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{2n}{2n+1}\right)^{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I Can't see where the serie goes.

I opened N terms, but I'm having some issues. If someone can help. The series is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{2n}{2n+1}\right)^{n^2}$$

Comment: We don't know what you mean by "solve."  Do you want the series evaluated, or just want to know whether it converges (in which case, I'd try the root test.)

Comment: Using the binomial theorem, we have

$$\left(2n\over2n+1\right)^{n^2}=\left(\left(1-{1\over2n+1} \right)^n\right)^n\le\left(1-{n\over2n+1}+{n(n-1)\over2(2n+1)^2} \right)^n\\=\left(5n^2+5n+2\over8n^2+8n+2\right)^n\le\left(2\over3\right)^n$$

so

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(2n\over2n+1\right)^{n^2}\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(2\over3\right)^n=2$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root test implies that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg[\left(\frac{2n}{2n+1}\right)^{n^2}\bigg]^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2n}{2n+1}\right)^{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n}\right)^{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1/2}{n}\right)^{n}}=\frac{1}{e^{1/2}}=e^{-1/2}<1,$$
so the series is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. Setting 
$$
u_n=\left(\frac{2n}{2n+1}\right)^{n^2}
$$ one has
$$
0\le \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac1{\sqrt{e}}<1
$$ then one may conclude by the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#The_test).